# Django/Python register page

Tags: python, html, django, http, authentication

I'm making a register page for my django (version 2.0) website, but it pretty messy to me, I'm pretty sure the bullet points and the additional information is not supposed to show up right away.

How can I make this register page look cleaner? Ie. just the username, password, and confirmation textbox, rather than all the messages.

Thanks!

[image]

Register.html

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<br>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Register view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'todo/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: can you post the form validation and all the messages you have added in the place

Comment: Things would have been simpler if you had specified 1. the django version and 2. if that was the contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm or your own UserCreationForm...

Comment: Added the version (2.0) and it's the supplied contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

1. Overriding the default `UserCreationForm()`

   `class MyForm(UserCreationForm):
       email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
       email.help_text = ''
       ...`
2. In the view template instead of using `{{ form.as_p }}` render the form manually

   `<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.username.label }}
       {{ form.username }}
   ...
   </form>`
3. Design your custom template and map the field name to the form field name.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify where this UserCreationForm came from nor your django version, but anyway: searching django's code source it appears that those are the help_text for the various widgets / fields of the default `contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`, so yes the "bullet points and the additional information" **is** actually "supposed to show up right away". And as far as I'm concerned (from a user perspective I mean) it's a good thing that it does "show up right away", so I don't have to retype username and passwords twice, thrice or more until I found out by trial/errors what the system expects (or, more often, just plain give up registering on this site).

Now if you really want to frustrate your users (and loose half of them on the way), you *can* of course mask all those useful informations by [rendering the form manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) so you have full control on which messages appear, when, where and how.